# Add a header to each request using .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want to add a custom header to a phpbb installation without touching the code. (Using .htaccess)

The header is:

```
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=157680000
```

Any ideas?

Comment: +1; Interesting question. Since you wan't to use .htaccess I assume that you have acceses to the server system. Just curious, but why do you wan't to solve this via htaccess?

Comment: I don't want to edit the vanilla phpbb installation.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

```
Header add Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=157680000"
```

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_headers.html

Comment: I would add a check if the module is loaded.<br/>
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        Header add Strict-Transport-Security "max-age= 157680000"
    </IfModule>

Comment: I would only test for module if the behavior is optional. Otherwise, it is more difficult to debug...

Comment: Don't forget to activate the apache module headers `a2enmod headers`

Answer (score 6):

see http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_headers.html

```
Header add Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=157680000"
```

Comment: I tried adding this to the .htaccess file and it just produces a 500 internal server error.

Comment: Don't forget to activate the apache module headers `a2enmod headers`