# No cache for some html pages

Tags: php, html, caching, refresh, no-cache

I've a code that every time fill in a HTML file with a new content and this file is called on my website by  ... but when I change the file content and then go to my page, the page shows the old content and not the new one. I just have 2 pages that I do that, the others are all statics.

How can I just have a "non-cache" for those 2 files?

My code its just like this:

```
<?php
$fp = fopen('file.html', 'w');
fwrite($fp, $content);
fclose($fp);
?>
```

and on another file.php I have

```
<html>
<head>...</head>
<body>
<some html>
<?php include(file.html); ?>
<some html>
</body>
</html>
```

thanks,

Comment: depends on what is caching it. Are you using a server-side cache? Or relying on the browser?

Comment: relying on the browser.

I have a linux with apache running on it.

Comment: How are you caching? Can you post some code for us to review?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that for that file a header is sent which specifies that it should not be cached; headers like:

```
Cache-Control: max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: Fri, 20 Mar 2014 00:00:00 GMT
```

If these files are PHP files you can do this by adding a line like this at the top:

```
<?php
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: no-cache');
header('Expires: Fri, 20 Mar 2014 00:00:00 GMT');
?>
```

The reason why I used multiple headers here is that there are multiple ways to control the cache; if you really want to make sure it is *never* cached, you should disable all forms (this way).

If they are purely HTML files, then you'll need to use some .htaccess magic as described in [this answer (add a header to each request using htaccess)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1570673/add-a-header-to-each-request-using-htaccess)

For clarity, this would be done as follows:

- Create a .htaccess file in the directory of your file.html
- Put the following content into this .htaccess file:

Code:

```
<files "file.html">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
    Header set Pragma "no-cache"
    Header set Expires "Fri, 20 Mar 2014 00:00:00 GMT"
</Files>
```

Comment: The thing is, i'm generating the .html reading the data and putting it on a $var and after writing it on a file.html using fwrite($file,$var);

if I set the header using PHP i'd be setting the filewritter.php headers and not the file.html.

I saw the htaccess but it just have ExpireByType html/css that is used for every html file and not just those 2 files that I'm looking  for

Cheers

Comment: you can always limit it to only a single (or a couple) of files by using `<Files "x.html"> Header add ... </Files>` as explained in the [Apache Documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#files)

Comment: Yes, but It don't have just "Expire", It has ExpireDefault and ExpireByType [link](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_expires.html) 

Or if I just put

<Files "file.html">
ExpiresDefault "access plus 6 hours"
</Files>

will it get the default expire just for the file?

If I just add

ExpiresByType text/html "modification plus 6 hours" and I modify (by fwrite) will it after 6 hours expires the cache?

Comment: Thanks @Tularis

I actually didn't do as you said but I did this and it worked

ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType text/html M0

it expires all the html since they are modified, exactly what I was looking for

Cheers

Comment: yes it would, remember though that `"Expire"` is a header, while `ExpireDefault` is a `setting` which then auto-generates an `expire`-header. Using the method I posted the expiration-date is in the past, so it will *always* not-cache the document.