# Why my php included file changes does not reflect

Tags: php

I made a website in php and created three include files. 
Header.php 
Footer.php 
and my content files. 
about.php, our-services.php, contact-us.php and 404.php

and called these inside my default.php

```
<?php  include('includes/header.php');  ?>

<div id="main">

<?php
    $url = '';
    $urlX = 'includes/404.php';
if (!empty($_GET['post_slug'])) {
    $url .= 'includes/';
    $url .= $_GET['post_slug'] . '.php';
    $GetPage = $_GET["post_slug"];  // validate string!!  

    if (!file_exists('includes/' . $GetPage . '.php')) {
               include $urlX;
    }
    else{
                include $url;
            }
    }
?>

</div>

<?php include('includes/footer.php'); ?>
```

my .htaccess file is coded like this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteRule    ^pages/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$    /default.php?post_slug=$1    
[NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

Now my about.php file has some basic information. 
so when i write domain.com/pages/about it shows my about.php and it works :)

the problem is when I make changes inside header or footer or in any file, my changes are not reflected. I have to press `ctrl + f5` on every page. If I am at domain.com/pages/about it will reflect the changes on this page only so when i go to another page, the header and footer shows previous cached files and i have to again press `ctrl + f5` on every page to see the changes. Every change on any included file doesn't reflect... please let me how to fix this problem.

Thanks

I have tried to add clearstatcache(); like this

```
<?php
clearstatcache();
$url = '';
$urlX = 'includes/404.php';

if (!empty($_GET['post_slug'])) {
    $url .= 'includes/';
    $url .= $_GET['post_slug'] . '.php';
    $GetPage = $_GET["post_slug"];  // validate string!!  

    if (!file_exists('includes/' . $GetPage . '.php')) {
               include $urlX;
    }
    else{
                include $url;
clearstatcache();
            }
    }
?>
```

but doesn't work...

Comment: Are you using some kind of framework?

Comment: Try to disable the cache within your browser. Developer tools -> Network

Comment: @Areg no framework. its just simple website.

Comment: @MarkusZeller It will only work for me. :) its a live website and i made changes,  uploaded files tested my self. but doesn't reflect to public..

Comment: i think you better check your hosting provider settings, somethings wrong with the servers and its constantly caching everything

Comment: @Areg I am using siteground's cpanel. I am raising ticket their. :)

Comment: @shabab also have you tried the same things locally?

Comment: *I have to press ctrl + f5 on every page*, are you using cdn? but you may try to apply [`Cache-Control` headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control) on your responses to ensure end user cache is cleared if it too old.

Comment: It is the clients browser who always want to cache to provide best possible speed. You could force refreshing by appropriate headers or add something like a version parameter to the URL `index.php?ver=1.0`. When you do an update, increase.

Comment: @MarkusZeller i have added ?v=1.0 like `<?php  include('includes/header.php?v=1.0'); ?>` it doesnt work with included files :)

Comment: @BagusTesa Can you give me a hint, how can I add cache-control headers. Inside default.php which has include code `<?php include('includes/header.php); ?>`.. or inside the header.php? thanks

Comment: in `.htaccess` file, add `HEADER add Cache-Control "max-age:7200"`, see [this QA for example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1570688/4648586). it will tell the browser to only cache the page for 2 hours. curious question, do you use any CDN (Content Delivery Network)?

Comment: You need to perform the parameter versioning on the URL not on the include. The Browser does not see the PHP internals.

Comment: @BagusTesa I have added it.. lets see... No i don't use any CDN.

Comment: @MarkusZeller I only have a single page and I use this  `RewriteRule    ^pages/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$    /default.php? post_slug=$1 [NC,L]` Rule. So I think there is no way that I could add any versioning :( the `the php include('header.php')` does not work with versioning. I raised ticket in siteground about the cache issue.

Comment: As suggested before, try using sending headers. @BagusTesa pointed to the right direction. Try shorter intervals for testing and increase later.

Comment: @shahab, if you use CDN they might require you to purge cache on their end also apart from just setting the headers. but most of the time though, they respect the headers.