# Cross-Origin Policies (COOP and COEP) in htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I got a notification from google that I should enable COOP and COEP on my website. The complete notification from google:

```
For Web Compatibility reasons Chrome is planning to require COOP/COEP for the use of SABs from Chrome 91 (2021-05-25) onwards. Please implement 'cross-origin-isolated' behavior on your site.
```

While searching for it online, I found following page:
https://web.dev/coop-coep/

On the above page, it is written to add the following:

```
Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy: require-corp
Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy: same-origin
```

My question is how do I add the above lines in my .htaccess file so that it works in apache.

Comment: Did you try and research this at all …? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1570673/add-a-header-to-each-request-using-htaccess

Comment: Yes I have searched a lot about these 2 headers. These look new from google. By following the format of other headers in htaccess, I came up with the following Header set Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy "require-corp"
Header set Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy "same-origin"  but not sure if that is correct

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm OP's above comment. Add the following two lines to the web server's `.htaccess` file to enable COOP/COEP:

```
Header add Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy "require-corp"
Header add Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy "same-origin"
```